# Quando instanciar e quando não instanciar o objeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

Vendo uma vídeo-aula de ***PHP*** aprendi que se pode usar uma classe de duas formas, *sem instanciar* o objeto e *instanciando o objeto*.

```
// Forma 1    
echo SEO_URL::Strip('Caçador mata leão na selva');

// Forma 2
$url = new SEO_URL();
$url->Strip('Caçador mata leão na selva');
```

Quando instanciar e quando não instanciar o objeto?

Comment: Note que o primeiro com `::` você apenas chamou um método estático e funciona geralmente somente com `static`, geralmente emite um `notice` se você não usa `static`, isto é comum em outras linguagens também.

Comment: Sei que as perguntas parecem diferentes, mas a resposta lá explique a duvida, eu acho.

Answer (score 2):

No que você chama de "*Forma 1*" (ou classe não instanciada) é nada mais que um simples "wrapper" para um conjunto operações ou definições, é até mais fácil pensar nisso como uma pequena caixa de ferramentas  ou utilitários, daí porque há a tão comum classe Utilities ou Util que na maioria das vezes não precisam ser instanciadas.

Por outro lado, classes que precisam ser instanciadas geralmente são concebidas para representar unicidade.
Um clássico exemplo disso é uma classe PESSOA, por exemplo, onde cada pessoa é representada através de um objeto único:

```
class Pessoa 
{
    public $cpf;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($nome, $cpf)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

$pessoas = array(
    new Pessoa('João', '000'), 
    new Pessoa('Pedro', '111'),
);
```

Há de se convir que há aqui uma real necessidade de criar uma instância para representar cada pessoa, o conceito de pessoa, há uma representação de **identidade**.

Especificamente o seu caso, se a classe SEO_URL é apenas uma classe que abriga um conjunto de operações comuns e não há uma real necessidade de identidade, tudo bem não criar uma instância dela e chamar os métodos estaticamente (claro , presumindo que ele assim foram definidos).